# Update Table 1 taking value from table 2

Tags: mysql

I want to update Table 1 by taking the value from Table 2. Both the tables have Emp No which is a key. I want to update the Salary column in Table 1 with the value that is present in Table 2

```
UPDATE TEST.tbl1  --< first the table that will be updated
JOIN   TEST.tbl2
ON     tbl1.IDNo = tbl2.IDNo
SET    Salary = Salary (From Second Table)
```

When i tried this iam getting an Error.. It says Error at or before the TEST..

Please anyone help me

Comment: Specify what table the field is taken from for all fields: `Set TEST.tbl1.Salary = TEST.tbl2.Salary`. And remember - if more than one record in `tbl2` matches to a record from `tbl1` than a random record will be used for updating.

Comment: *It says Error at or before the TEST* Is `TEST` the name of your database? if not remove `'TEST.'` substrings.

Comment: TEST ---Is the name of the region of my Database (eq Test, Prod, INTG)

Comment: Database region? What's that? Server-Database-Table-Record-Field, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl1, tbl2
SET tbl1.Salary = tbl2.Salary
WHERE tbl1.IDNo = tbl2.IDNo
```